# Do not autocomplete certain extensions from file names in shell for vim

Tags: bash, macos, vim, bash-completion

I've noticed a really cool feature of bash-completion in bash.  Let's say I have a directory with files

```
a.java
a.class
b.java
b.class
```

if I start typing `vim a` <kbd>Tab</kbd> , bash will autocomplete `a.java`.  It knows I don't want to edit `a.class`

I was wondering how it achieves this behavior.  In my `bash_completion.d` directory there are a bunch of `completion` files, but `vim` does not have one.
How does `vim` achieve this behavior, and how do I modify it to include other file extensions to ignore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Ubuntu, if I install the package `bash-completion`, I can see its contents with:

```
$ dpkg -L bash-completion
```

In the output, `/etc/bash_completion` is listed.
Inside, the following command is written:

```
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

It sources the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

The location of these files [vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730453/do-not-autocomplete-certain-extensions-from-file-names-in-shell-for-vim/52731166#comment92409841_52731166) from an OS to another:

> Note: I use a Mac, and on macOS the bash-completion file is stored (by default) in `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion`, and the `bash_completion.d` directory is in `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d`

On my system, `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` contains this line:

```
_install_xspec '*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)' vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview emacs xemacs sxemacs kate kwrite
```

I think this line is responsible for the behavior you're observing.

If you want to tweak it to make bash exclude the `foo` and `bar` extensions when completing a filename after the `$ vim` command, you could try the [following procedure](https://serverfault.com/a/831184).

1. Create the file `~/.bash_completion`

Inside the latter, write:

```
for bcfile in ~/.bash_completion.d/* ; do
  [ -f "$bcfile" ] && . $bcfile
done
```

2. Create the `~/.bash_completion.d/` directory.
3. Inside this directory, create a `vim` file.

Inside the latter, write:

```
complete -f -X '*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class|foo|bar)' vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview
```

`complete` is a bash builtin command which allows you to specify how arguments to a command name should be completed.
`-f` is a shorthand for `-A file`, which specifies to bash that you want to see only filenames in your suggestions.
`-X` excludes anything which matches the following pattern.

Note that I have merely copied the pattern used in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, and added the `foo` and `bar` extensions:

```
*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class|foo|bar)
                                                                           ^^^^^^^
```

It's up to you to modify the pattern to exclude the real extensions you want to avoid.

The names after the pattern tell bash for which commands should it exclude these extensions.
In the previous command, they are:

```
vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview
```

All of them invoke a version of Vi or Vim. You could add other editor names at the end.

For more information see:

```
$ man bash
```

Look for the `READLINE` section and the `Programmable Completion` subsection, as well as the description of the `complete` builtin in the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section.

See also [An introduction to bash completion part 1](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1) and [An introduction to bash completion part 2](https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2).

Comment: Great first answer, with proper formatting and lots of references; thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome answer.  Great formatting!  Thanks for the great answer and all the references, I will be sure to check them out!

Comment: Note: I use a Mac, and on macOS the bash-completion file is stored (by default) in  `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion`, and the bash_completion.d directory is in `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d`